# Magento 2 query url rewrite

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, nginx, query, apache

If I have URL like this -

> **mainpage.com/products?test_category=99**

and want it to be rewritten to this

> **mainpage.com/testproducts**

Since magento2 URL rewrite won't take query how can this be achieved with apache and nginx rewrites?

Comment: url_key for the category?

Comment: url_key for category is **products** and page is loaded by given collection id which in this case is 99.  so **mainpage.com/products** is given this query **?test_category=99** to load collection on this url **mainpage.com/products?test_category=99** which needs to be rewriten

Comment: rewriteing mainpage.com/products?test_category=99 to mainpage.com/testproducts is easy in Apache or Nginx, what are other cases? Are there other parameters than test_category? What should happen with the values? Can you generalize the requirements for the rule you need?

Comment: There are many pages whose collections are generated like this. But rewrite is only needed for this specific url with param 99

Answer (score 2):

For apache you can use the following - for example just put it into your `.htaccess` file in the document root directory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/products.*$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*test_category=99.*$
RewriteRule .* /testproducts? [R=301,NC,L]
```

This does a 301 redirect. If you just want to serve the content (i.e. internal rediect so the client still sees the original URL) please remove `R=301` from the rule's option list.

The question mark at the end of the rewrite url means that the query string will entirely be removed (even if there are other parameter except the test_category)

Update: For the updated requirement that `/products?test_category=99` should redirect to `/testproducts` and this page should server the content from `/products?test_category=99`. In order to avoid endless redirect loops, we need to append a parameter for the internal redirect which helps us to skip the first redirect rule. If the parameter `redirected=1` is a problem for the `/products` URL choose one which fits.

```
#Redirect /products?test_category=99 to /testproducts
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/products.*$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*test_category=99.*$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^test_category=99&redirected=1$
RewriteRule .* /testproducts? [R=301,NC,L]

#Serve content from /products?test_category=99 for /testproducts
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/testproducts$
RewriteRule .* /products?test_category=99&redirected=1 [NC,L]
```

Update for URLs that have to pass the Magento routing: In this case the `REQUEST_URI` is used by Magento and this will not be overwritten by the last rule in the example above. A solution in this case is to use the P-flag for the RewriteRule. In this case the Apacehe mod_proxy module needs to be installed!

```
RewriteRule .* /products?test_category=99&redirected=1 [NC,P]
```

Update with a better variant using Magento's rewrite routing for the second rewrite `/testproducts` to `/products?test_category=99`: Just add a url rewrite with `request_path = 'testproducts'` and `target_path = 'products/test_category/99'` and in Apache's `.htaccess` file only the first RewriteRule is needed.

I hope that helps.

Comment: unfortunately this did nothing

Comment: Sorry I've copied the wrong one first time in my answer,  I have updated it, the query_string needs to be separately

Comment: will try this tommorow and update if it works. Cheers

Comment: Now if going to this **mainpage.com/products?test_category=99** Url rewrites to **mainpage.com/testproducts**, but the content of first url is not loaded on the second url, so I'm prompted with 404. And When going directly to **mainpage.com/testproducts** 404 aswell.

Comment: So you want to redirect from `mainpage.com/products?test_category=99` to `mainpage.com/testproducts` and `mainpage.com/testproducts` should serve the content from `mainpage.com/products?test_category=99`? Is that right? If yes it will become a little more complex :-)

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I tried to achieve.

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer for this case

Comment: This is a great explanation, thank you. Redirect works as intended but content is not served. 404 still. Is this called silent rewrite?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90078/discussion-between-helgeb-and-trenox).

Answer (score 0):

```
location / {
    if ($arg_test_category = 99 ) {
        return 301 https://mainpage.com/testproducts;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: you dont need `if` to do a simple rewrite

Comment: @MagenX how will you approach redirect for URL with specific parameter then?

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite

Comment: @MagenX the question is about redirecting based on specific URL *argument* in original URL. The `rewrite` directive has no idea about those. It can only either discard or append existing parameters, not take decision to redirect based on the value of an argument

Comment: maybe using map+rewrite to load multiple regex'ed variants. just loking for options

Comment: Maps will be useless in this case because you will end up using `if` even then. The provided solution is simplest.

Comment: no, you dont need `if` :)

Comment: You will need `if`