# Magento 2 Make GET Request url to rewrite acceptable

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, request

For example I have this url which makes get Request and renders block with specific collection by Id.

> **mainpage.com/products?some_category=99**

Since Magento 2 Url Rewrites only accept /params/paramsvalue how could I rewrite my type of url to make it rewrite friendly like this

> **mainpage.com/products/some_category/99**

Comment: Did you find a solution for your rewrite issues from your both questions? I didn't get any feedback on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/263057/76597 I hope you've got the problem fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rewrite rules. Either with parameter `some_category` set with any value:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/products.*$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^some_category=(.*)$
RewriteRule .* /products/some_category/%1? [R=301,NC,L]
```

or more general for any parameter and any value:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/products.*$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)=(.*)$
RewriteRule .* /products/%1/%2? [R=301,NC,L]
```

You might want to combine this with the rewrite from your other question regarding the rewrites ([Magento 2 query url rewrite](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262818/magento-2-query-url-rewrite/262884)), that should be possible but anyway there still may be the issue with the internal rewrite and you need to proxy pass the rewritten request.

The above examples do a 301 redirect, for internal rewrite just remove the `R=301` flag, for proxy pass change it to `P`